# Assigning different colors to numerical values below a certain parameter?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, color, math-operators

I'm relatively new to Latex so apologies for any stupidity upcoming.

I'm trying to read a Matlab vector into a latex table with values ranging between 0 and 1. For the values less than 0.1, I want them to be returned in the color blue but can't seem to manage it.

Here is the code I've been using (Bold and Italic symbolising Latex Code, everything else are Matlab related)

strcat(***' & \color{blue}\ensuremath{<0.1}{\numprint{'***,sprintf(format3,M4_tot(i)),***'}} \ '***  )];

What this has been returning is values such as '<0.1 0.837' where <0.1 is the Mathematical operator I wish to recognise and 0.837 is merely an example from my Matlab vector. Essentially, I don't know how to make Matrix recognise my operator, all it does it print the data. Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by mathematical operator `'<0.1'`? Also, if your vector in Matlab is `a=[0.2, 0.01, 0.8]`, what do you want to print in the LaTeX table? `0.2 & {\color{blue} 0.01} & 0.8` or something else?

Comment: '<' or less than is my Mathematical operator. I want to say that if values in my Matlab vector are less than 0.1, return them as blue in my Latex table. If the values are greater than 0.1, print them as normal (black). So in your example vector a, that is exactly what I'd want to print!

Answer (score 1):

This MATLAB script writes one row of your LaTeX table for a vector:

```
a = rand(1, 10); 
threshold = 0.1;

fid = fopen('table.tex', 'w');

for i = 1:length(a)
  if(a(i) < threshold) 
    pstr = ['{\\color{blue} ' num2str(a(i)) '}']; 
  else
    pstr = num2str(a(i)); 
  end

  fprintf(fid, pstr);
  if(i ~= length(a))
    fprintf(fid, ' & ');
  end
end 

fclose(fid);
```

You can then include the produced file in the tabular environment as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
    \input{table.tex}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```